# Python, read one byte out of n bytes with np.fromfile

Tags: python, numpy

I have pixel data in a binary file.
The size of the file is 4096 * 4096 * 3 bytes

I read the file as follow:

```
file = r"my_img.rgb"
data = np.fromfile(file,dtype=np.uint8)
```

With this code I load the full 4096 * 4096 image.

Later in my code I resize this image in size 1024 * 1024

My question is the following:

Is it possible to read only one byte out of 16 with the `np.fromfile()` function ? Like that I would have my image resize directly

Comment: May be possible in numpy but I don't actually know. However, you could just open the file using built-in Python functionality and read the bytes you need building a buffer as you do so, then present that to numpy

Comment: @BrutusForcus I tried something like this, but my code is unfortunately very slow

Comment: Maybe `numpy.memmap` is a good approach here?

Comment: It's probably simpler, safer, and may even faster to load the whole thing and `resize` after loading.  If the loaded shape is (4096,4096,3), then a pixel is represented by 3 bytes, and every 4th pixel has to 'skip' 12, take 3, etc.  Even if you don't use a `cv` like resize, slicing the from loaded array will probably be faster. BUT, I haven't done much timing of `fromfile`.

Answer (score 1):

This may give you an idea of how you could approach this. I have created a file that's exactly 48MB and and I can read it and build a bytearray containing every 16th byte (which is what I understand you're trying to do) in <400ms:

```
import time

thefile = '48mb.bin'
start = time.perf_counter()
with open(thefile, 'rb') as bigfile:
    buffer = bigfile.read() # read entire file into memory
    newbuffer = bytearray([0]*(len(buffer)//16)) # pre-allocate
    for i in range(0, len(buffer), 16):
        newbuffer[i//16] = buffer[i]
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f'{end-start:.4f}')
```